# Python how to patch a function in another module and call it internally?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In original.py, it is not controlled by myself

```
def func():
    print("func")
```

Is there a way to patch original.func?

patch_original.py, it is controlled by myself

```
def patched_func():
    original.func()
    print("patched_func")
```

call.py

```
import original # can not change this
import patch_original


func()
```

---

I want to be able to print

> func
>
> patched_func

---

Update:
original.py is not under my control.

patch_original.py is fully controllable.

call.py is partially under my control, it has already **import original**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of patch is perfect for the decorator pattern:

In `original.py`:

```
def func():
    print("func")
```

In `patch_original`:

```
def patch(f): # this function is a decorator
    def p():
        f()
        print("patched_func")
    return p
```

In `call.py`:

```
import original
import patch_original

func = patch_original.patch(original.func) # here we decorate `original.func`

func()
```

Running `call.py`:

```
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ python call.py
func
patched_func
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$
```

Then you can resuse this patch as you define new function in `call.py`:

```
import original
import patch_original

func = patch_original.patch(original.func)

func()

@patch_original.patch # decorator syntax
def func2():
    print("func2")

func2()
```

And running this:

```
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ python call.py
func
patched_func
func2
patched_func
```

Comment: This looks interesting, my goal is to minimize the change against call.py, and do most work in module patch_original, can I move the patching statement to patch_original?

Comment: Hm, honestly, I would keep the patching where it's going to be *used*, at the top. You won't have to modify any of the rest of the code. But I suppose you could do it in `patch_original` but you have to `from patch_original import func`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The background: I need to provide patch_original to my customers in order to provide some extra services. They will use it in online python environment. That means minimizing the changes to their main script will provide better user experience.

Comment: @user1633272 Also, note, if you `import original` in `call.py`, then really `func` will be `original.func`.

Comment: Does that mean I have to explicitly call 'func = xxx' assignment statement in call.py? Actually I have about 6 functions need to be patched. That's why I want to hide it from call.py.

Comment: @user1633272 it depends on how `original.py` is being imported. Note, as written, if you just `import original.py` and try to use `func()` it will give a `NameError`, so, you need to figure out exactly how things are already working in `call.py`

Answer (score 0):

Do this in `patch_original.py`:

```
import original

_original_func = original.func

def patched_func():
    _original_func()
    print("patched_func")
```

Then in your main script:

```
import patch_original
func = patch_original.patched_func
```

Answer (score 0):

**original.py**

```
def func():
    print("func")
```

**patch_original.py**

```
import original

def patched_func():
    original.func()
    print("patched_func")
```

**call.py**

```
import original
import patch_original

patch_original.patched_func()
```

Comment: The environment needs to import original in call.py. And I shouldn't change the calling statement in call.py.

Comment: Ok you can have "original.py" imported but never used. I updated.